# Oracle SQL inserting parenthesis into phone number

Tags: sql, oracle, formatting, substring, concatenation

The original format:

```
123-456-7890
```

My goal format:

```
(123)456-7890
```

I wanted to go the route of concatenating between substrings but I continually get flagged for errors. I am unsure of a better method to go about implementing a way to format.

My query:

```
select || '(' || substr(telephone,0, 3)|| ')' || 
substr(telephone,4, 3)|| ' '|| 
substr(telephone,7, 4)) as telephone,
from book;
```

My current error:

```
"missing expression"
```

Comment: Do you absolutely *have* to do it in the database engine?

Comment: Yes which is inconvenient. There is documentation for other parenthesis insertion just not in the same environment as this.

Comment: I understand what occurred now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an extra dangling parenthesis at the end of your `SELECT`, and you also have a dangling concatenation operator `||` in the front.  Try this:

```
SELECT '(' || SUBSTR(telephone, 0, 3) || ')' ||
    SUBSTR(telephone, 4, 3) || ' ' || SUBSTR(telephone, 7, 4) AS telephone
FROM book
```

**Update:**

You should really use this query, because it turns out you also had a problem with forming your desired output as well:

```
SELECT '(' || SUBSTR(telephone, 1, 3) || ')' || SUBSTR(telephone, 5, 8) AS telephone
FROM book
```

Comment: @lolocpp Oh dear...you had a `||` operator in _front_ of the `SELECT`.  It should run now as I have removed this.

Comment: It is incorrect, since it would give output `(123)-45 6-78`. But, you need `(123)456-7890`. There is no need of `' '` i.e. a space.

Answer (score 0):

Using **SUBSTR**:

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '123-456-7890' num FROM dual
  3  )
  4  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  5  SELECT num,
  6    '('
  7    || SUBSTR(num, 1, 3)
  8    ||
  9    ')'
 10    || SUBSTR(num, 5, 8) AS my_num
 11  FROM sample_data;

NUM          MY_NUM
------------ ---------------
123-456-7890 (123)456-7890

SQL>
```

Remember, the **index** for **SUBSTR** starts from `1`. It is bad practice to use `0` as starting index.

You could also do it using **REGEXP_REPLACE**.

Pattern: `(\d{3})(-)(\d{3})(-)(\d{4})`

Expression: `regexp_replace(num, '(\d{3})(-)(\d{3})(-)(\d{4})', '(\1)\3\4\5')`

For example,

```
SQL> WITH sample_data AS(
  2  SELECT '123-456-7890' num FROM dual
  3  )
  4  -- end of sample_data mimicking real table
  5  SELECT num,
  6    regexp_replace(num, '(\d{3})(-)(\d{3})(-)(\d{4})', '(\1)\3\4\5') my_num
  7  FROM sample_data;

NUM          MY_NUM
------------ ---------------
123-456-7890 (123)456-7890

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regular expressions` to do.

```
select regexp_replace
(phoneNo,
  '([[:digit:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{3})\-([[:digit:]]{4})',
  '(\1)\2-\3'
) 
from(
select '123-456-7890' as phoneNo from dual)
```

Output

```
(123)456-7890
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT '123-456-7890','('||SUBSTR('123-456-7890',1,3)||')'||SUBSTR('123-456-7890',5,8) FROM dual;
```